# How to store prices in Couchbase without losing precision?

Tags: json, couchbase, currency

I have a Couchbase database and I would like to store `price` without losing precision - double is really not good enough for my application. However, it seems that there is no support for currency data types in Couchbase.

Is there a preferred solution for this problem for this database engine?

I was thinking about storing each price twice, once as string and once as double, so that I can still query price for inequality. It's better than nothing but not really a nice solution.

Comment: Can you tell me more about problems with doubles? JavaScript uses 64 bit numbers with a 52-bit mantissa and 11-bit exponent. Is 52-bits really not enough for representing your prices? Or are you running in to rounding issues?

Answer (score 1):

This is really a problem with JSON, but since Couchbase uses pure JSON, it applies :)

One solution that I've seen is to store it as an integer.

For example, if you want to store a price of $129.99, you would store a number of 12999. This could be kinda annoying, but depending on what language/framework you're using, it could be relatively easy to customize your (de)serializer to handle this automatically. Or you could create a calculated property in your class (assuming you're using OOP).  Or you could use AOP.

But in any case, your precision is stored. Your string solution would also work, with similar caveats.

Comment: I'm not sure that storing as an integer would be any better, since JavaScript treats all numbers as 64-bit floats, whether integer or no.